# Null pointer exception Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger

Tags: null-pointer

I am trying to default the Account Name in a case to 'abc corp' but while executing the code, it gives the error

> Attempt to de-reference a null object. its happening at line 10 which
>   c.account.name = defaultAcc.Id

.

The code

```
trigger DefaultAccName on Case(after insert, after update) {

    Account defaultAcc = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM Account
        WHERE Name ='abc corp'];

for (Case c: trigger.New) {

    if (defaultAcc.Id != null)
     { 
      if(c.Type=='Internal')
         {
           c.account.name = defaultAcc.Id;
         }
         }
    }
}
```

Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

Deepak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a trigger, "related" objects aren't automatically queried; this means you can't use `c.account.name` without first querying it. Also, if you're trying to update the account's name, you'd need a DML operation. Based on your code, I'd assume you meant `AccountId` instead:

```
if(c.Type=='Internal') {
    c.AccountId = defaultAcc.Id;
}
```

Also, this must be a "before insert, before update" trigger, or you'll get a "read-only record" error.

Comment: Hi i am trying to update the Account name (which is a lookup field) in the case object.

Comment: @deepaknagarajachary just follow above code you will get what you are expecting.

Comment: Double thumbs up.. Yes it worked after i made the above change. Thank you for all your help on this.